# Ansible sudo_user not using the correct $HOME directory

Tags: git, solaris, ansible

I have a git directory that is owned by a user that I cannot ssh as. I'm currently using `sudo_user: user` which is working but does not seem to be setting $HOME correctly. My user account has github in the ~/.ssh/known_hosts file but it is being added to my ~ssh_user/.ssh/known_hosts file (from the accept_hostkey=yes).

http://docs.ansible.com/git_module.html

```
- hosts: myhost
  sudo_user: user
  tasks:
    - name: git
      git: repo=git@github.com:user/repo.git dest=/home/user/repo update=no accept_hostkey=yes
```

Is there something I need to do to tell ansible to use $HOME correctly?

I'm running on Solaris off of Joyent but I don't think that's directly applicable to this problem.

Answer (score 8):

add sudo_flags in your **ansible.cfg** file

```
[defaults]
sudo_flags = -i
```

this will run you **sudo user**'s login script to populate environemt variables like $HOME

Answer (score 3):

`sudo` does some mangling with a bunch of environment variables, notably `HOME`. You can check this with :

```
sudo -u user | grep HOME
```

If you get `/home/user`, you're fine, but you probably get `/home/ssh_user`.

This is really something related to `sudo`, not to ansible.

To circumvent this, you can add in `/etc/sudoers` :

```
Defaults    always_set_home
Defaults    set_home
```

Try again `sudo user | grep HOME`, you should get proper result.

If not, check for a `Defaults env_keep` sudo directive. It can also play a role here. Hunt for `Defaults env_keep += "HOME"` in `/etc/sudoers`, and **remove** it (this directive asks sudo to preserve `HOME` from the user issuing sudo)

Good luck.

EDIT: These directives might also appear in `/etc/sudoers.d/`. I don't know about Solaris, so YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

We use some joyent smart os machines. I get around the problem by setting the environment like below. That will work for some application.

```
- name         : Test Envirinment
  hosts        : all
  gather_facts : no
  tasks:
    - name: echo host
      shell: echo $HOME
      sudo_user: someuser
      environment:
           HOME: "/var/lib/dir"
```

or you can use the suggest solution by @leucos that would be a more permanent solution

Hope that helps cheers

Answer (score 1):

just use `become_flags` at task level

```
- hosts: myhost
  become_user: user
  tasks:
    - name: git
      git: repo=git@github.com:user/repo.git dest=/home/user/repo update=no accept_hostkey=yes
      become_flags: '-E'
```